# Making sense out of VSTS logging commands task.addattachment, task.uploadfile, artifact.upload and build.uploadlog

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two artifacts that I download from my Octopus server in order to expose in my vNext build (we are using an on-premises TFS).

The code is:

```
$Artifacts.GetEnumerator() |% {
    curl $_.Value -OutFile "$TestResults\$($_.Key)" -Headers @{
        "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $ApiKey
    }
    Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=NUnitTestResults;name=$($_.Key);]$TestResults\$($_.Key)"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadfile]$TestResults\$($_.Key)"
    Write-Host "##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder=NUnitTestResults2;artifactname=$($_.Key);]$TestResults\$($_.Key)"
    #Write-Host "##vso[build.uploadlog]$TestResults\$($_.Key)"
}
```

Two files - `CSTests.xml` and `PSTests.xml` are downloaded and placed in a folder. Then I am issuing the VSTS logging commands.

The only documentation I could find for them is https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md and it leaves a lot of space to our imagination.

What I have learned so far:

**build.uploadlog**

Embeds the contents of the files in the log of the respective task. For example:

[image]

As one can see, the NUnit test results are prepended to the step log proper. And here is what the documentation says:

[image]

I hope it makes sense to somebody, to me it does not make any. Next:

**artifact.upload**

This one is easy - it adds the files as artifacts to the build:

[image]

But each artifact contains **ALL** the files. So, it does not matter which Explore button I click (for `CSTests.xml` or `PSTests.xml`), I always get this:

[image]

Sounds like I am expected to place the two artifacts in different container folders, but then what is the purpose of having both the container folders and the artifact names? I am confused.

**task.uploadfile**

Using this one I got my NUnit test result files included in the log archive when downloading logs:
[image]
[image]

No questions here.

**task.addattachment**

This one is a mystery to me. It has no apparent effect. The documentation says:

[image]

Not clear what kind of an attachment it is and where can we find it.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a serious documentation for the VSTS logging commands beyond the half baked aforementioned markdown page?
2. `build.uploadlog` - does it always prepend the contents of the files to the step log or appending is also an option?
3. `artifact.upload` - how publish files as separate artifacts? Does it mean separate container folders? But then the name of the file is likely to be mentioned in two places - container folder and artifact name. Is it the way?
4. `task.addattachment` - what does it do?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Nope. Did not have time to pursue it.

Comment: this is the page I found, but it's not much better: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands

Answer (score 0):

I've been similarly frustrated with the documentation for these logging commands.

As for `task.addattachment` I discovered the [Build/Attachments REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/attachments/list) and the attachments show up there. It has this format:
`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/attachments/{type}?api-version=6.0-preview.2`

Note that `type` is required. You simply use the same `type` that was specified in the `task.addattachment` command.

I was able to build a url and just plug that into my browser window. Then it displays the raw json response.